# Entity Framework Core 3.1 One to many relations - Only getting first child entity for parent Fluent API Syntax

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

hoping to get some help with data retrieval using EF Core 3.1. I have two entities that have one-to-many relationships. However, they will be connected by email address which is not a primary key in either of these tables. I did declare a property in the parent entity that holds the ICollection of the child entity, and there is no property declared in the child entity that references the parent since I don't want that.  The problem here is I am always getting the first child entity for the ICollection property, even though I know there are more. Here is the code snippet:

** Property declared in the parent for the child:

```
public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
```

** Here is the fluent API code in parent entity type configuration:

```
    builder.HasMany(e => e.Contacts)
            .WithOne()//Since child entity doesn't have any property to hold the parent
            .HasPrincipalKey(x => x.UserName)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.EmailAddress);
```

Here UserName field in the Parent entity is connected with emailaddress field in the child entity.

** Here is the fetch call:

```
public override async Task<List<User>> Fetch(Expression<Func<User, bool>> filter)
{
return await _context.Set<User>()
.AsNoTracking()
.Where(filter)
.Include(x => x.Contacts)    
.ToListAsync();
}
```

This code is always giving me the first child entity, even though I know there are more. What exactly I am doing wrong here. I would really appreciate your help here. Thank you.

Comment: Is `UserName` *unique* in parent entity? i.e.  is `_context.Set<User>().Count() == _context.Set<User>().Select(x => x.UserName).Distinct().Count()` true?

Comment: So you have multiple contacts associated to one person all with the same eMail address??

Comment: Hello @IvanStoev Yes UserName is unique in parent entity. Just checked again. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, all of those child entities will have some email address. Thanks @StevePy

Comment: How about the string casing then? Do they match (client vs database)? i.e. `_context.Set<User>().Select(x => x.UserName).AsEnumerable().Distinct().Count()`? Hidden spaces and non printable characters? Does this happen for *all* or just *some* parents?

Comment: I am not aware of such anomaly @IvanStoev. Can we handle this with HasPrincipalKey and HasForeignKey or any other way? I was actually looking for a way to do this by comparing as upper case and trim.

Comment: In general the related column values must match exactly, that's why normally we use `int` or `Guid` values for keys and not strings. Fluent API is just for mapping (to specify the related columns of the relationship), they cannot change the logic., which is `parent.Children = db.Children.Where(c => c.ParentKey == p.Key)`, which in SQL terms is equi-join. EF Core has something called value converters, but I don't think they apply to key comparisons/joins in SQL. You need additional computed "normalized" columns in the database, like `IdentityUser` class (from MSFT) name and email.

Comment: It would be much easier if you can change the database and introduce real FK referencing the parent PK. But before that, just run and check the result of the queries I wrote in the previous comments (and more if needed) in order to be sure that is the problem, and not EF Core implementation bug. EFC 3 is quite old now, many things were changed/bugs fixed (and new introduced :-) in 5.0, 6.0, so we can't exclude that possibility. But again, check our code/data first, then EF Core issue tracker.

Answer (score -1):

Use **HasDiscriminator** in child class mapping in following way:

```
public class ChildClassMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ChildClass>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ChildClass> builder)
    {
        //Custom entity configurations here

        builder.HasDiscriminator<string>("ChildClass");
        
    }
}
```

You can also use directly in **OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)**. You can go through documentation for more details:
[Inheritance - Entity type mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance)